# virtualbox problems

Tags: virtualization

I'm running Ubuntu linux 12.04 and trying to install a version of Windows OS onto my virtualbox. I already have Win 7 ultimate running and I would like to also run Win 8 from .iso file. I've been using the win7 vbox for a while, which I installed with a .iso using a bootable usb. I am trying to do the same thing-only now with a different os booted onto my usb but I can't seem to get it to to work. After creating a new machine and trying to boot so I can install win8 I get this message:

> Fatal: No bootable medium found! System halted.

During the first run wizard I chose the .iso file as the media. Should I have chosen the default? I've tried that too and same message. Does this have anything to do with needing the virtualbox extenstion packages? Because I've tried downloading those and run into errors as well. It doesn't seem like I should need them however, as I installed my other windows without them. I will provide more info if needed, thanks for any help.

Comment: For Windows, see http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-a-virtual-machine-image-of-your-existing-hard-drive-windows/ and http://superuser.com/questions/251599/tuning-windows-7-for-use-in-a-vm - but is your PC running the Virtual OS on a Linus PC? If so, which version and model number?

Comment: Reworded to include info about ubuntu, please take hold off or give further instruction, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the settings in virtualBox's *Settings -> Storage* where you can make other changes including selection of CD/DVD drive or virtual disk image files to use..

[image: snap1]